# Automatic stopped getting locaton from gps

Tags: android

We are facing the problem that is getting the location from GPS frequently in background service but some times stopped location automatically in open area while I am sure that service is continuous running and do not affect deep sleep situation also in device idle mode. Please, some body help.

initLocationManager() method is calling one-minute interval through background service.

```
 private void initLocationManager() {
 Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
 if (mLocationManager == null) {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) 
 getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 }
 if (mLocationListeners == null) {
    mLocationListeners = new MyLocationListener();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                Constant.LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                Constant.LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners);
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        mLocationManager = null;
        mLocationListeners = null;
        WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, 
   AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + 
   "20" + "\n");
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        mLocationManager = null;
        mLocationListeners = null;
        WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, 
      AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + 
    "21" + "\n");
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        mLocationManager = null;
        mLocationListeners = null;
        WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, 
   AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "22" 
   + "\n");
        Log.d(TAG, "System Exception! Thread has no looper." + 
    ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        mLocationManager = null;
        mLocationListeners = null;
        WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, 
   AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "23" + 
   "\n");
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        mLocationManager = null;
        mLocationListeners = null;
        WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.ERROR_LOG, true, 
  AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + ex.getMessage() + "24" 
   + "\n");
    }
    }

    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location == null) {
        //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, 
    AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " NULL" + "\n");
        return;
    }
    //lastUpdatedTime = 
    Constant.SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(location.getTime());
    if (location.getAccuracy() < 50) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        // WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, 
   lastUpdatedTime + " "+location.getLatitude() + ","+ 
   location.getLongitude() + "AC"+ "\n");
    } else {
        if (latitude == 0.0 || longitude == 0.0) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, 
   lastUpdatedTime + " "+location.getLatitude() + ","+ 
   location.getLongitude() + "NON AC"+ "\n");
    }
}

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    switch (status) {
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, 
  AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " AVAILABLE" + "\n");
            //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, 
 "Last Update Time" + lastUpdatedTime + "\n");
            break;
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, 
  AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " OUT_OF_SERVICE" + "\n");
            // WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, 
  true, "Last Update Time" + lastUpdatedTime + "\n");
            removeLocationManager();
            mLocationManager = null;
            mLocationListeners = null;
            break;
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, 
    AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " 
    TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE" + "\n");
            //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, 
   "Last Update Time" + lastUpdatedTime + "\n");
            removeLocationManager();
            mLocationManager = null;
            mLocationListeners = null;
            break;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, 
    AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " PROVIDER ENABLEE" + 
    "\n");
    }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    //WritingFile.getInstance().writeFile(Constant.COORDINATE, true, 
   AppManager.getInstance().getCurrentDateTime() + " PROVIDER DISABLE" + 
   "\n");
   }
  }
```

Comment: Did you try changing minDistance  and minTime in requestLocationUpdates? Even I too got this problem. I used toast to display latlang and toast used to display latlang even if the app was closed. So I changed minTime and minDistance(in terms of km). Still I didn't tested but you may try like this.

Comment: Yes I have passed value MinTime = 0 & Min Distance = 0